# 2 tuples equal the same when printed and are in unicode but when compared they dont match Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, tuples, cgi-bin

I am trying to get data out of a sqlite3 database which I know returns a tuple using `cursor.fetchone()` but for some reason when the user on the other program which is a CGI script submits the data and I take it in and print it the 2 match up as in their passwords so when I try to compare them they never match:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3 as lite
import cgi

db = lite.connect('qwerty0987654321.db')
usrnme = "none"
passwd = "none"
passver = "none"

def main():
    global usrnme
    global passwd
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head><title>Profile</title></head>"
    print "<body>"

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    if form.getvalue('username'):
        usrnme = form.getvalue('username')
        if form.getvalue('passwd'):
            passwd = form.getvalue('passwd')
            if isauth() is True:
                print "Welcome %s" % usrnme
            elif isauth() is False:
                print "Wrong username or password!"
        else:
            print "No Password!"
    else:
        print "No Username!"
    print '</body>'
    print '</html>'

def isauth():
    global usrnme, passwd, passver
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT password FROM Users WHERE username = ?",(usrnme,))
    passver = c.fetchone()[0]
    passver = tuple(passver,)
    passwd = tuple(passwd[0],)
    if cmp(passwd,passver) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        print(passver,passwd)
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So what *is* printed then? Please show us the output of the `print` statement. As a rule, CGI posts are **not** decoded to `unicode` objects anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your error is here:`passwd[0]`. Because str's can be indexed, it would refer to the character at the first position in the str. That would be `'n'`:

```
passver = c.fetchone()[0]  # get the first field in the first item in the result set
passver = tuple(passver,)  # add it to a tuple.
passwd = tuple(passwd[0],) # add passwd[0] (n) to a tuple
```

That won't work. Try instead:

```
passver = c.fetchone()[0]  # get the first field in the first item in the result set
passver = tuple(passver,)  # add it to a tuple.
passwd = tuple(passwd,)    # add all of passwd to a tuple
# comparrison should succeed depending on contents of Users
```